# Set a value of an EditText from a Selected Spinner Items List

Tags: android

I am using the below code to get the value of the spinner and set it to the EditText **tehsil** but it doesn't work. The dropdown is working fine but the value is not setting the **tehsil**

```
 @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    //first spinner item position
    int districtSpinnerPosition = spinnerdistrict.getSelectedItemPosition();
    switch (districtSpinnerPosition) {
        case 0: //1st item of 1st spinner selected
            //fill data for second spinner
            fillKharanTehsils();
            ////////////// Set EditText of Tehsil
            tehsil.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean hasFocus) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (hasFocus) {
                        spinnertehsil.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do `tehsil.setText("My text");`